# OpenCv Stereoscopic Vision

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to use a heat map in a stereoscopic reading. I have two cameras that do the depth function (stereoscopy), but how to identify the closest point (which should turn red) and the size?
It is an accountant of people using stereoscopic vision.
It's something like the video below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lCQehzmUuc
I used the code on this page (http://timosam.com/python_opencv_depthimage) and it worked, but I want to know how to map the heat, to identify the object closest to the camera and the size of this object.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import cv2

print('loading images...')
imgL = cv2.imread('imgL.jpg')  # downscale images for faster processing if you like
imgR = cv2.imread('imgR.jpg')

# SGBM Parameters -----------------
window_size = 3                     # wsize default 3; 5; 7 for SGBM reduced size image; 15 for SGBM full size image (1300px and above); 5 Works nicely

left_matcher = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(
    minDisparity=0,
    numDisparities=160,             # max_disp has to be dividable by 16 f. E. HH 192, 256
    blockSize=5,
    P1=8 * 3 * window_size ** 2,    # wsize default 3; 5; 7 for SGBM reduced size image; 15 for SGBM full size image (1300px and above); 5 Works nicely
    P2=32 * 3 * window_size ** 2,
    disp12MaxDiff=1,
    uniquenessRatio=15,
    speckleWindowSize=0,
    speckleRange=2,
    preFilterCap=63,
    mode=cv2.STEREO_SGBM_MODE_SGBM_3WAY
)

# FILTER Parameters
lmbda = 80000
sigma = 1.2
visual_multiplier = 1.0

wls_filter = cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(matcher_left=left_matcher)
wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)

print('computing disparity...')
displ = left_matcher.compute(imgL, imgR)  # .astype(np.float32)/16
dispr = right_matcher.compute(imgR, imgL)  # .astype(np.float32)/16
displ = np.int16(displ)
dispr = np.int16(dispr)
filteredImg = wls_filter.filter(displ, imgL, None, dispr)  # important to put "imgL" here!!!

filteredImg = cv2.normalize(src=filteredImg, dst=filteredImg, beta=0, alpha=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
filteredImg = np.uint8(filteredImg)
cv2.imshow('Disparity Map', filteredImg)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Comment: Can you share an image from both the cameras? My guess is that you need to calculate differences in offsets between the images as these offsets will trick the brain into perceiving depth.

Comment: I used this code http://timosam.com/python_opencv_depthimage and it worked, but I want to know how to recognize the area closest to the camera and the size of this area, using a heat map as in the video I uploaded.